# AngularJS Carousel Menu

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, carousel

Got a question regarding AngularJS and a carousel menu. I've made an array and I have trouble inserting the data in my View.

Controller:

```
gameApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
 // Gamemodelist is static. Put all the corresponding gamemodes in an array
    $scope.gameModeList = [
        {"name": "Waterworld", "contents": [
            {"name": "Classic", "contents": [
                {"name": "Level 1", "contents": [{"name": "beginner"}, {"name": "easy"},{"name": "intermediate"}, {"name": "ultimate"}]},
                {"name": "Level 2", "contents": [{"name": "easy"}]}
            ]},
            {"name": "Firemode", "contents": [
                {"name": "Level 3", "contents": [{"name": "beginner"}]}
            ]}, 
            {"name": "Watermode", "contents":[
                {"name": "Level 4", "contents": [{"name": "introduction"}]}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"name": "Fireworld", "contents": [
            {"name": "Classic", "contents": [
                {"name": "Level 1", "contents": [{"name": "Intro"}, {"name": "Beginner"}, {"name": "Intermediate"}]},
                {"name": "Level 2", "contents": [{"name": "Beginner"}, {"name":"Intermediate"}]}
            ]},
            {"name": "Fireworld", "contents": [
                {"name": "Level 3", "contents": [{"name": "Beginner"}, {"name": "Intermediate"}]}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"name": "Tutorial", "contents": [
            {"name": "Basic Tutorial"}, {"name": "Battle Training"}
        ]}];
}
```

This array is basicly the menu itself. You see the first items in the array are the first items in the menu. And every array in the contents is the submenu and if there is a subsubmenu.
This is my controller. Now I'm new to Angular, and I've already mate routing and templating work. Got different controllers for the login screen and the options screen. But now I'm working on the homescreen, which features a menu and I'm quite uncertain what's my best step here. I've already decided that I don't want to use different pages like I'm doing with my login and options screen, because I feel that an array is more convenient, because it already features the ordering of the items and it's (imo) a bit more managable.

To the view then. I've already checked and I think I need to use ng-if to check if there are submenu's in the array and if so use ng-repeat to display the menu. But. I come from jQuery background, so my instinct was to display the list and make it work with CSS and jQuery to manipulate the DOM so the items are shown which I want them to show, I know (for sure) that thats how things work in Angular. I guess I need to check with the controller which items need to display?

```
 <ul>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="mode in gameModeList">
      {{ mode.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Now I only get the first items in the list obviously. I guess I now have to get the contents of the item I click in the view?

Comment: Are you looking for something along these lines? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6cmz8L2/)

Comment: Yeah this is just exactly what I was looking for... Now I got a question regarding displaying this data. I can insert this data in the dom and use jQuery or something like that to display the right menu items (just like I do on a normal webpage).. But this isn't how you are supposed to use Angular right?

Comment: Angular handles all of the DOM rendering and using jQuery on top will not bode well with $digest cycles. You could write a directive to handle all of this and it's the Angular way of doing so.

Comment: Ok thanks, any suggestions which route I have to take (regarding this menu display?) I'm diving into directives, thanks for the input!